# Java string format condition

Tags: java, string, format, conditional-statements

I want to write a sentence that is dependent on person's gender, here is what i could do:

```
String createSentence(String name, boolean isMale) {
    return String.format(isMale ? "I met %s, he was OK." : "I met %s, she was OK.", name);
}
```

but you already see the fail in that (it works, but code is duplicit), i want something like:

```
String createSentence(String name, boolean isMale) {
    return String.format("I met %s, %b?'he':'she' was OK.", name, isMale);
}
```

This ofc doesn't work, but is something like this possible?

EDIT:

Since I will want many sentences to be generated, even in different languages, and they will be stored is some sort or array, thus this solution is unhandy:

```
static String createSentence(String name, boolean isMale) {
    return String.format("I met %s, "+(isMale?"he":"she")+" was OK.", name);
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work? [Your example works perfectly.](http://ideone.com/LXNdBd)

Comment: Yes, it *does* work, but it generates duplicity

Answer (score 22, accepted):

How about

```
return String.format("I met %s, "+(isMale?"he":"she")+" was OK.", name);
```

or

```
return String.format("I met %s, %s was OK.", name, (isMale ? "he" : "she"));
```

---

If you can change type of `isMale` to integer which for instance would represent mapping

- `0`->`she`,
- `1`->`he`

you could use [MessageFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) and its `{id,choce,optionValue}`

```
static String createSentence(String name, int isMale) {
    return MessageFormat.format("I met {0}, {1,choice,0#she|1#he} is fine",
            name, isMale);

}
```

Comment: Yea, this solves this particular problem, i simplifed the question too much, my apoligies, i'll edit the question.

Answer (score 3):

You could go for a combination:

```
String createSentence(String name, boolean isMale) {
    return String.format("I met %s, %s was OK.", name, isMale? "he": "she");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String.format("I met %s, %s was OK.", name, isMale ? "he" : "she");
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using an `enum`?

```java
enum Gender {

    FEMALE("she"), MALE("he") /* ... */;

    private final String pronoun;

    private Gender(String pronoun) {
        this.pronoun = pronoun;
    }

    public String pronoun() {
        return pronoun;
    }

}

private static String createSentence(String name, Gender gender) {
    return String.format("I met %s, %s was OK.", name, gender.pronoun());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(createSentence("Glenda", Gender.FEMALE));
    System.out.println(createSentence("Glen", Gender.MALE));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the pronoun itself and then not have to worry about any condition.

```
static String createSentence(String name, String pronoun) {
        return String.format("I met %s, %s was OK.", name, pronoun);
}

String sentence = createSentence("Fred", "he");
```

If you need to use boolean variables, you could implement a decorator.

Answer (score -2):

Try this :

```
 return "I met "+String.format(isMale ? " %s, he " : " %s, she ", name)+" was OK."
```